# Vue.js watcher not executed when manually setting value

Tags: vue.js

I have this Vue component:

```
methods: {
  ...
  toggleTyping: function () {
    this.composing = !this.composing;
  },
  ...
},
data: function () {
  return {
    composing: false,
  };
},
watch: {
  composing: function (val) {
    alert(val);
  }
}
```

When I execute `toggleTyping()` the watcher is not called. I'm very new to [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs).

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: @BertEvans i'm using `<button v-on:click="toggleTyping()">show</button>`. The `toggleTyping()` function is beeing called correctly and the value is changing (because I can see it on the screen).

Comment: What version of Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you are showing works. The error must lie elsewhere.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  methods: {
    toggleTyping: function() {
      this.composing = !this.composing;
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      composing: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    composing: function(val) {
      alert(val);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggleTyping()">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks everyone, the problem was really weird, I had a function also declared in the body of the component called `type` (it was making a typing animation, so I choose that name). When I renamed that function it started to work!

I put the **failing** code to clarify and help anyone else:

```
 ....
    ,
    type : function () {
        ...
    },
    watch: {
        composing: function (val) {
            alert(val);
            //Never called!
        }
    }
```